# jq How to filter array object does not contains Key with case insensitively?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jq, aws-cli

I am trying to filter my aws ec2 instances by its Tag Key.
I want to get the result that ec2 instance does not have specific Key(in my example, it is env or appname)

```
aws ec2 describe-instances | jq -c '.Reservations[].Instances[] | select(contains({Tags: [{Key:"env"}]}, {Tags:[{Key:"AppName"}]} | not) | {instanceId: .InstanceId, tags: .Tags}'
```

which returns
However I noticed that I mixed uppercase and lowercase in Key, for example

```
{
 {
  "InstanceId": "t-1234",
  "Tags": [
         {"Key": "Name",
          "Value": "Foo"},
         {"Key": "env",
          "Value": "prod"}
        ]
 },
{
  "InstanceId": "t-1235",
  "Tags": [
         {"Key": "Name",
          "Value": "Bar"},
         {"Key": "Env",
          "Value": "prod"},
         {"Key": "AppName",
          "Value": "BarApp"}
         ]
 },
{
  "InstanceId": "t-1236",
  "Tags": [
         {"Key": "Name",
          "Value": "Bar"},
         ]
 },
}
```

With this example, my desired output will be,

```
{
 {  // this instance does not have AppName
  "InstanceId": "t-1234",
  "Tags": [
         {"Key": "Name",
          "Value": "Foo"},
         {"Key": "env",
          "Value": "prod"}
        ]
 },
{  // this instance does not have AppName and env
  "InstanceId": "t-1236",
   "Tags": [
         {"Key": "Name",
          "Value": "Bar"},
         ]
 },
}
```

I have been searching and reading that I need to use either `ascii_downcase` or `ascii_uppercase`, but keep failing applying. How can I improve my jq statement so that I can filter ec2 instances which do not have specific Key case-insenstiviely(like, `env` or `ENV` or `Env`)?

Thanks

Comment: Please follow the [mcve] guidelines. In particular, your sample is not valid JSON.  Also,  the object with .InstanceId equal to "t-1234" does have a Tag with .Key equal to "env", which is one of the values that is supposed to exclude the object. Please therefore clarify the requirements.

Comment: @peak Even though `t-1234` has a Tag with .Key equal to `env`, it does not have `AppName` that I want to filter out from the my json object. Please let me know if it is still unlcear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding of the problem description (as opposed to the example) leads me to this jq program:

```
map(select( any(.Tags[]; .Key | ascii_downcase | IN( "env", "appname")) | not))
```

Hopefully, the use of `any` and `IN` here will guide you to the formulation you want.